# Applying bitwise shift operators to signed types: UB and Impl. defined

Tags: c++, bit-shift

C++03 standard tells us that the result of applying the bitwise shift operators to signed types can be UB and Impl. defined for **negative** values. My question is following: why for operator `<<` it has **undefined behaviour**, while for operator `>>` it is just **implementation defined** ? Is there a strict reason why the result of `<<` couldn't be implementation defined also ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to 5.8/2 (admittedly in C++ 98 which is all I have access to):

> The value of E1 << E2 is E1
>   (interpreted as a bit pattern)
>   left shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
>   bits are zero filled. If E1 has an
>   unsigned type, the value of the result
>   is E1 multiplied by the quantity 2
>   raised to the power E2, reduced modulo
>   ULONG_MAX+1 if E1 has type unsigned
>   long, UINT_MAX+1 otherwise.

From this it looks to me like it's perfectly well defined for left shift. What's not defined is the representation of signed values (such as twos-complement) used so the numeric *value* of the result is implementation defined for negative values.

This is in contrast to right-shifting where the vacated bits may be zero or one filled depending on the representation of signed values.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I have misunderstood this and thought that this was defined only for the case when does not have signed type and negative value

Comment: Ah, got it now, it was undefined in C and I accidently had a moment look at ISO C99 (6.5.7/4) :) Thanks for explanation.